# How can I add the text on the top of the gridview in QML?

Tags: qt, gridview, qml, qt5

I am designing a layout in my program. I want to add a text on top of the gridview, but I just can make them overlap together. How can I add the text on top of the gridview? Thanks.

[image]

My code:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.8
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import com.contentplayermod.filemodel 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id:main_win
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Player")
    property int idx: 0
    property bool isActive: true

    Row {
        Text  {
            id:text1
            anchors.bottom: grid_main.top
            width: 240
            height: 35
            text: myModel.folder.toString()
            font.family: "Helvetica"
            font.pointSize: 20
            color: "blue"
            focus: true

        }
    }


     GridView {
                       id:grid_main
                       anchors.fill: parent
                       anchors.top: text1.bottom
                       cellWidth: 100; cellHeight: 100
                       focus: true
                       currentIndex: 0
                     ...

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in the `GridView` you are setting the anchors in a conflictive way, on the one hand you indicate that it occupies the space of main_win, and on the other hand you indicate that the top anchor is the Text Item.

What you must do is that the `GridView` has as the top part the Text, and the other anchors are from the parent.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id:main_win
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Player")
    property int idx: 0
    property bool isActive: true

    Text  {
        id:text1
        anchors.top: parent.top
        width: 240
        height: 35
        text: myModel.folder.toString()
        font.family: "Helvetica"
        font.pointSize: 20
        color: "blue"
        focus: true

    }

    GridView {
        id: grid_main
        // annchors
        anchors{
            bottom: parent.bottom
            right: parent.right
            left: parent.left
            top: text1.bottom
        }
        cellWidth: 100; cellHeight: 100
        focus: true
        currentIndex: 0
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I have tried your method, but the text disappears. Only a gridview is shown.

Comment: @OPfan 
I just tried it and you're right, I'm going to see what the problem is